# Spline graph not showing in highchart

Tags: json, highcharts, max

I am using highchart with codeigniter. My json data is like below,

```
[{"name":"zreadactivity","data":["E-Juice","Tank Kit & Accessories","Clearomizers","Cartomisers & Accessories","Starter Kits"]},{"name":"TotalValue","data":["11,320.00","6,629.52","5,184.43","2,691.75",353.85]}]
```

Data is coming but spline graph is not created. Only last value is showing in graph that is 353.85, others are not displaying. 
Is there any thing for higher value? or where I stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In data you should have array of points with number values, not strings as you have. So you need to convert your json to correct form, during preprocessing or return json in correct form.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian, but can you give a example for that?

Comment: I got solution for that..Thank you @Sebastian.
I just put str_replace function where I pass the variable for json data.

Comment: I got solution for that..Thank you @Sebastian.